# Alternate constructor for a case class

Tags: scala

```
trait mobility {
   def limit : Int
}

final case class Car {
  brand : String,
  manufacture : Int,
  override val limit: Int
} extend mobility

object Car {
  def apply(
    brand : String,
    manufacture : Int,
  ): Car = Car( brand , manufacture , 0)
}
```

Compilation error :

> Cannot resolve overloaded method "Car"

What am I doing incorrect here?

Comment: If you fix all typos then it works as expected: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/zn0wFihWSbe1Eayj6Jg89Q/4

Comment: Considering the amount of questions and their nature, did you go through some free basic Scala course like Coursera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code will not compile. You have a syntax error in the definition of the case class

```scala
final case class Car {
                     ^
```

The attributes of the class should be wrapped inside a parentheses instead of a curly braces.

Another error you have is that the reserved word to inherit a class is `extends` not `extend`

```scala
} extend mobility
  ^^^^^^
```

just fixing that, it should work.

Check this [scatsie example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RAPGBYjYR46qmAcq54LXTg) using your code with the suggested fix